# How do I add error handling to this code of racket?

Tags: parsing, error-handling, racket

This is a parser for a radar made in racket script that connects through tcp to DCS-world (A flight simulator video game) how can error checking be implemented to this code? what would the procedures of the error handler check for and what should the procedure output as statements?

```
 (define/public (parse)
            ; needs error checking
            (if (and (equal? jsexpr (json-null)) (not (equal? jsonstr "")))
             (set! jsexpr (string->jsexpr jsonstr) )
          null)

        (set! azimuth (hash-ref jsexpr 'Azimuth) )
        (set! id (hash-ref jsexpr 'ID) )
        (set! power (hash-ref jsexpr 'Power) )
        (set! priority (hash-ref jsexpr 'Priority) )
        (set! signaltype (hash-ref jsexpr 'SignalType) )
        (set! radartype (hash-ref jsexpr 'Type) )
        (if (member 'TypeInts (hash-keys jsexpr))
          (set! typeints (hash-ref jsexpr 'TypeInts))
          null)
        (set! airborne (airborne-type radartype typeints) )
        ;(set! highpriority (high-priority this typeints))
        (set! awacs (if (and
                  (= (car typeints) 1)
                  (= (cadr typeints) 1)
                  (= (caddr typeints) 5)
                 ) #t #f))
        (set! tracking (if 
                 ( and (equal? signaltype "lock") (equal? (modulo i 5) 0))
                 #t 
                 #f
                 )
          )
```

Comment: This looks like imperative code written in a functional programming language.

Comment: That `if ... set! ... null` statement should be a `when` expression instead, if you're determined to write this imperatively

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do? I suggest linking to a gist of the whole class, since due to your use of `set!` it's impossible to tell what the scopes of the variables you're using are.

Comment: All in all, you may want to move this to the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site